# AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'show'

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

Encountering error with plotly:

```
from plotly import graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
prediction = model.predict_generator(test_generator)

close_train = close_train.reshape((-1))
close_test = close_test.reshape((-1))
prediction = prediction.reshape((-1))

trace1 = go.Scatter(
x = date_train,
y = close_train,
mode = 'lines',
name = 'Data'
     )
 trace2 = go.Scatter(
x = date_test,
y = prediction,
mode = 'lines',
name = 'Prediction'
     )
trace3 = go.Scatter(
x = date_test,
y = close_test,
mode='lines',
name = 'Ground Truth'
    )
layout = go.Layout(
title = "Google Stock",
xaxis = {'title' : "Date"},
yaxis = {'title' : "Close"}
  )
fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1], layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

Can someone help in resolving this? I tried upgrading plotly to the latest version but even that did not help.

Comment: Please, show the output of `print(plotly.__version__)`. Thanks.

Comment: My version is 4.1.0